# how to select the numbers of my sim that i have in my listview android app to further use that number for transfering balance

Tags: android

i have used these lines of code to view my phone contacts in a listview

```
cursor1=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor1);
String [] from ={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
int [] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
SimpleCursorAdapter listadaptor= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,cursor1,from, to);
setListAdapter(listadaptor);
lv= getListView();
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Please add a description of the problem. Is the issue that you now want to select a number or that you want to access numbers from the sim?

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon i want to select the specific number from that list for further purpose. for example there are 10 number in my list and i want to select any one of the number and whenever i select that number i must be able to use that in another activity. hope i was able to explain